# Which episode of Dragon Ball / Dragon Ball Z characteres started to have auras?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball

I was trying to make a list of all auras the Z fighters had in Dragon Ball, and knowing which episode characteres started to have auras will save me a lot of time. Which episode of Dragon Ball / Dragon Ball Z characteres started to have auras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how strict of a definition for aura you're going for. What I mean is it would be one of two events:

First, it could be when Master Roshi first performs the kamehameha in the original Dragon Ball series. He has a slight white aura around him. This is the first example of ki in the series so it may be what you mean. See: [YouTube video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdQLaHEpx9w)

Second, a more conventional aura would be when Gohan headbutts Raditz in the beginning of Dragon Ball Z. When he breaks out of the attack ball he gains a read aura and then proceeds to headbutt Raditz. See: [YouTube video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ko0XtJjJ28)

Comment: what about the more typical white/transparent aura we see in most good characteres when they power up

Comment: Well I think it'd be when Goku first fights Vegeta, so around 1:37 here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWYk6kSpHtk